# How to pass object array to a function?

Tags: c++, function, object, inheritance, arrayobject

```
class department
{
    void max() ***HOW TO PASS ARRAY OF OBJECT HERE , WHAT PARAMETERS SHOULD I PASS***
    {
    } 
};

class B : public department {
};

int main()
{
    B a[10];
   
    // a.max(a,n);  ***HOW TO CALL THIS max FUNCTION***
    return 0;
}
```

I want to pass the array of object `a[10]` to the `max` function. How do I call it and pass it?

I don't want to do it like this:

```cpp
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a[i].max
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `for` loop? That seems like an acceptable solution.

Comment: You made `max` a member function of the class, so you have to call it on an instance. If you want to have a function that takes an array of `department`s then you have to write such a function

Comment: The exact syntax `a.max(a,n);` is impossible, because `a` is not a class (but rather an array).

Comment: Nitpick: `max` is implicitly a _private_ member function of `department`.  The child class `B` therefore does not have access to `max`, so even given an instance of `B` to call `max` on, you will get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implemented `max()` as a **non-static** method of `department`, so you need a `department` object to call it on, like each `B` object in your array, eg:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    a[i].max();
}
```

If this is not what you want, then `max()` needs to be taken out of `department`, or at least made to be `static` instead.  Either way, you will have to change its input parameters to accept the array.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
class department
{
public:
    static void max(department *depts, int count)
    {
        //...
    } 
};

class B : public department {
};

int main()
{
    B a[10];
    department::max(a, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/5mX3pF)

Alternatively:

```cpp
class department {
};

class B : public department {
};

void max(department *depts, int count)
{
    //...
} 

int main()
{
    B a[10];
    max(a, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/8t6tSr)

Answer (score 1):

> How to pass object array to a function?

The parameter of a function cannot be an array in C++. A parameter can be a reference to an array. Alternatively, it is common to pass iterator pointing to an element of an array. Object pointer is an iterator for an array.

`department::max()` is a non-static member function. It has empty parameter list, so it accepts no arguments at all, except for the implicit class instance that is used as the left hand operand of a member access operator. Since this function accepts no reference to array parameter nor a pointer parameter, there's no way to pass an array as an argument.

Here is an example of a function that does accept a reference to an array as a parameter, and of how to call such function:

```
void max(B (&arr)[10]);

int main()
{
    B a[10];
    max(a);
}
```

Comment: yeah i got it , I was also asking what parameters should I have to pass in function max.

Comment: @VishalOjha There is nothing that you can do to pass an array into your function `department::max()`. I have shown how to pass an array to a different `max` function that does accept a reference to an array as parameter.